# GoogleApps Provisioning API to move a user from one organization to another

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-apps, google-api-java-client, google-provisioning-api

i have a use case to move a user from one Organization to another. The Api i am using is provisioning API. [Managing Org Users](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#managing_organization_users) gave an example for lab. Can anybody please share more info on what jar's need to be used to implement this. My rest of code is able to manage the other user functionallity. 
My Code is in java
I am using jars gdata-appsforyourdomain, gdata-client, gdata-core and gdata-collect. These jars dont have any API's to manage the organizations with users. It would be great help if any one can share docs or any sample data on this use-case. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the way by going through the source code of the labs  and deployed the same.

```
AppsPropertyService service=new AppsPropertyService(applicationName);
          service.setUserCredentials(adminUserName,Password);
          GenericEntry entry = new GenericEntry();
          entry.addProperty("oldOrgUnitPath",oldOrg);
          entry.addProperty("orgUnitPath", newOrg);
      service.update(new URL("https://www.google.com/a/feeds/orguser/2.0/"+cutomerId+"/"+MailIdofUserToBeMoved), entry);
```

customerid- is the unique key of the admin.